# Can we make the X Questions with new activity feed not load deleted spam title and body?

Tags: feature-request, spam

When loading new questions by pressing the *X Questions with new activity* button, spam posts are shown with title and a section of the body, even if they're already deleted as spam.

This likely substantially increases their exposure if they're quickly deleted, since any users that have the question show up in their feed still see their title and a section of the body.

Could we censor these questions, in the same way they're censored for >10K users?

Alternatively, we could just make them not show up when clicking this button, but that might cause confusion (3 new questions -> click -> 2 show up).

What happens:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sharing screenshots of spam posts on SE is OK when that adds to your post or providing additional information, as long as it's not NSFW.

Comment: AFAIK, the current behavior is fire-and-forget, thus SE won't monitor the existing buffered new questions and just show them as-is. I don't know if it's possible/cheap in computation for SE to recheck those questions before showing them... and to explain it effectively when there's number inconsistency...